# Using caps lock indicator for other purpose

Tags: keyboard, caps-lock

Can I use the caps lock indicator light for another purpose; like indicating that the current keyboard layout is Greek?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) + [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html) can get you that.

The starting point: is the “Change CapsLock Key” on this page: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/list.html.en.

Comment: Neither of the programs can control Caps Lock *light*. Their purpose is to  remap Caps Lock key to another key or key combination.